# `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityStopped` called without `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityStarted` in Android 9?

Tags: android, performance, android-lifecycle

I am seeing a crash recently, only in Android 9 devices:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
  at android.view.View.findFrameMetricsObserver(View.java:7279)
  at android.view.View.removeFrameMetricsListener(View.java:7250)
  at android.view.Window.removeOnFrameMetricsAvailableListener(Window.java:886)
  at androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator$FrameMetricsApi24Impl.remove(FrameMetricsAggregator.java:433)
  at androidx.core.app.FrameMetricsAggregator.remove(FrameMetricsAggregator.java:243)
  at PerfMetricsListener.remove(PerfMetricsActivityLifecycleCallbacks.java:xx)
```

Recently using [FrameMetricsAggregator](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/FrameMetricsAggregator) with [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks), adding the `Activity` in `onActivityStarted` and removing it in `onActivityStopped`. Looking at the `View` changes, there was a [fix for the NullPointerException](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/140ff5ea8e2d99edc3fbe63a43239e459334c76b) but it will still crash if no `FrameMetricsObserver` was added.

Looking at the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) it should not be possible, I wonder if maybe calling [Activity.finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finish()) or something else could introduce this behaviour. Have you seen this happening? What could be the reason?